# Would a plant need light if the chemicals gained by photosynthesis were given through the roots or as a foliar spray?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

If you took the chemicals a plant gains through photosynthesis and put it through the plants' roots or by injection, or used as a foliar application for intake through the stomata, would the plant need light? If not, how would it respond to the treatment?

Comment: Are you suggesting that someone would artificially supply a plant with sugar, proteins, lipids, etc. via the roots?  Isn't that sort of like putting a plant on a feeding tube?

Comment: Yes. Would it work?

Comment: This approach can be used to culture mycorrhizae http://www.jstor.org/stable/3760183

Comment: There are a couple autotrophic plants that parasitize other plants that kind of do this already. But you probably couldn't do it to any plant. But you could do it to some

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same thing, but a species of algae has been genetically altered to allow it to  uptake glucose, bypassing the need for photosynthesis: http://www.unisci.com/stories/20012/0615013.htm

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this would work for the vast majority of plants.  I think it would cause root rot as the microorganisms in the soil would out-compete the plant.  Also the transport systems of the plant might not be efficient in this direction.

I mean might there be a plant somewhere where this might work?  Sure.  Fungi that grow in the dark would be a lot like such plants, so its biologically possible.  There might be a primitive plant that doesn't need its chloroplast to be active to live.  I've never heard of one and wikipedia is not helping here...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotropa_uniflora